django-ckeditor-5 toolbar not showing
I was using django-ckeditor and upgraded to ckeditor-5 due to the end of support, but I can't see it on my front-end. works as it should in admin panel
admin panel:

front-end:

forms.py:
class CreateComment(forms.ModelForm):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.fields["text"].required = False

      class Meta:
          model = Comments
          fields = ['comment_content']
          widgets = {
              "text": CKEditor5Widget(
                  attrs={"class": "django_ckeditor_5"}, config_name="extends"
              )
          }

html:
{{ post|safe }}

Hi, I have been struggling with this for about 4 hours. Finally I figured out that I have to add into my base html template to the  section the  "{{ form.media }} # Required for styling/js to make ckeditor5 work", see it here: https://pypi.org/project/django-ckeditor-5/ at the "Example of using a widget in a template:" section.

for example


<div class="form-group mb-3">
<label for="description">Description</label>
{{ module_forms.description|safe }}
{{ module_forms.media }}
</div



Maybe you forgot the modul_forms.description|safe and the modul_forms.media,  It is important to place the modul_forms.media under the modul_forms.description|safe

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
